# Is it possible to prove that we found the shortest proof?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Initial considerations: using natural deduction as a logical system, we're limited to propositional logic, and we have a fixed set of basic rules of inference. Suppose that we cannot use any theorems of logic right away and if we want to use one we have to insert a proof of it in our argument.

Then we construct a proof of an arbitrary statement this way. My question is the following, is there a way to find out whether our proof is the shortest that can be constructed in a given logical system. The shortest means the one with the least number of steps, where every step corresponds to the one of basic rules or premise introduction.

Comment: You may want to look up the concept of "normalization" in Natural Deduction.

Comment: In addition to normalisation, you may want to look at §2 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10670-019-00112-7), in particular, the proof of theorem 2.3 and example 2.1. The natural deduction system presented by Dyckhoff in §5 of [his paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275431) on contraction-free sequent calculus can also be of interest. These suggestions, however, deal solely with intuitionistic logic.

Answer (score 4):

Let $N$ be the number of steps of the proof of your statement. Now look at the set of all proofs of length $< N$. This is a finite set of proofs. One can program a computer to enumerate all the proofs of lengths between $1$ and $N-1$, to list out the statements that each of them prove, and then to search through that list to see whether your statement occurs. Whatever the outcome of this search, you will have determined one way or another whether a shorter proof of your statement exists.

Comment: I don't understand: there are infinitely many derivations of length 1 (made up of just the axiom rule), one for any formula in the language.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco True ... but the statements you get will still be of a certain form. So, using statement variables, you can still keep your search finite.  But yes, it'll be a little more complicated than Lee suggests.

Comment: @Bram28 - What do you mean by "using statement variables, you can still keep your search finite"? Please, could you be more precise?  It sounds interesting, but I don't understand.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco He may be referring to how, due to (some versions of) natural deduction being normalizing, every expression in a normalized proof of a theorem is a subexpression of the theorem itself.  It still leaves to be resolved that only normalized proofs are the shortest, but it is at least a thing.